# Transfer Jar & Wars in one single remote server folder using Maven

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-release-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin

I am in the process of conversion of an existing project into Maven & their build and release process.
My structure is like this
ParentProj
-Child1
-Child2
-ChildWeb3
-ChildWeb4

I am not sure what the maven best practices says but I am required
1. To tag all my child projects separately
2. When I transfer to by deployment server (mvn release:prepare release:perform -B), it creates sort of repository
I want to make a folder in remote server & put all the jars & wars inside it only & no other files
3. Also Is there any way to execute shell script in my remote server

Awaiting your guidance

Answer (score 1):

What you're being required to do goes against the Maven conventions and recommended best practices.  Gotta remember, Maven does build and release, not deploy.  Yes, there is a deploy goal, but that goal takes the artifacts produced from the build or release and pushes it to the a remote Maven repository that is storing all versions of artifacts.  That repository structure is why your JAR and WAR files end up in different folders when you do the mvn release:perform, which is another way of asking maven to do a mvn deploy.

Now if you want to keep with the Maven way of doing things, you should write another script (shell, Ant, your choice) for deployment that would get those JAR and WAR files from the remote Maven artifact repository and bundle them up the way you want and deploy it to the server(s) you want them installed on.

Now, you can change maven to sort of do what you want your are asking, but you'll have to create another project/module that only does bundling of the JAR and WAR files in the way you want as an archive file (tar, gzip, zip). The Maven assembly plugin is the tool to do this job.  You can find out more about the assembly plugin [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/).  Now, keep in mind, mvn release:perform will still push the archive to the Maven repository.  You'll still need to have a deployment script to get the archive file from the remote Maven repository and extract it to the server you want to deploy it to.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out... I will follow what convention says.

Comment: Would also love to hear from you if you could throw some light on tagging multi module project

Comment: What I meant to ask is. Our project currently non maven based & tags all the project separately... Now since I converted them into maven module I am unsure about their tagging as till now I am only able to tag my parent project & the child modules following the parent tag. What does Maven best practices says.. shall I tag only the parent or tag child modules separately if yes then how ?

Comment: @Irshad - Your last comment would make another great question.  I would encourage to ask it as a separate question and gain reputation for it.  Also, if you're good with the answer for a question, it is in good courtesy to accept it.